# Calculating hashValue

Tags: swift, hash

My struct has a few properties and looks like:

```
struct Foo {
    var number1: Int
    var number2: Int
    var number3: Int

    // Has a lot more numbers and other properties

    var numbers: Int { return number1.hashValue ^ number2.hashValue ^ number3.hashValue }
}
```

When I compare some instances of Foo with `instance1.numbers == instance2.numbers`, it's too unreliable since it may or may not return `true/false`. So I fixed it by multiplying each number with a number before returning it:

```
var numbers: Int { return (100 * number1.hashValue) ^ (200 * number2.hashValue) ^ (300 * number3.hashValue) }
```

This seems to be working and have yet to find some unwanted results, but it doesn't seem like the intended way to do this. Is there some other (better) way to do this?

Comment: You need to come up with a good hash function.  Here is the study that can help you there:  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Answer (score 0):

Hash value never tells you if values are equal. It can tell you either values are not equal or they are probably equal. So if you want to compare two `Foo` instances using hash you have to perform it like this:

```
struct Foo {
    var number1: Int
    var number2: Int
    var number3: Int

    // Has a lot more numbers and other properties

    var numbers: Int { return number1.hashValue ^ number2.hashValue ^ number3.hashValue }
}

func ==(lhs:Foo,rhs:Foo)->Bool{
    if lhs.numbers==rhs.numbers{
        return lhs.number1==rhs.number1 && lhs.number2==rhs.number2 && lhs.number3==rhs.number3
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I've added a comment in the struct is because in other occasions, I have to compare the struct with all the other properties as well. Perhaps I should make a new struct for just the numbers?

Comment: @HennyLee if you want to compare two instances you must compare all it's properties. But if you comparing many times you can create guaranteed unique hash (string hash for example). I mean if you have `number1`, `number2` and `number3` fields you can create hash like this: `var hashString="\(self.number1)_\(self.number2)_\(self.number3)"`. Of course you have to renew hash if one of numbers is changed